# How to renew Apple developer account?

Tags: ios, developer-tools, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I would like renew my annual developer account.

It was not set to automatic renew. But there was still no renew button. So i updated my credit card information and filled out that weird new "survey". Still no renew button.

So i turned on automatic renew. It then said that the renew date would be 16. January (it was 15. January when i did it). But now nothing happened. It now says renew date is 30. January 2023. But there is no way i can wait that long. Apps we are using are not working anymore.

So how can i just give Apple my money and renew my membership now?

Tried enabling auto renew. Switching on and off.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023 Dec, if you don't see any renew button which means you have turned on the auto renew check box when signing in. So you could simply add money to apple account after the subscription ends and it will automatically get added to the subscription.

**Got to App Store -> Account Setting (Top right) -> Add funds;**

Add the fund required for the subscription and instantly it will get added to the account and then the renewal be done automatically by apple, I don't know why there are no docs for this, spend 5 days to find this.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to renew your membership is to contact Apple's developer support team. They will be able to help you renew your account and resolve any issues you may be having. You can reach them by visiting the Apple website's developer support page or by emailing developer@apple.com